# What tools do you use for coding efficiency and overall efficiency

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am relativly new to coding and am using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL 2008 for the most part. I am using resharper which is great, but I also found Launchy and StrokeIt which are both great free programs.

Are there any other programs people could recomend that are useful? This may not be the right way to post this but I was unsure where ask this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can look for plugins for visual studio 2010 here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/

Comment: That looks very useful for sure. I will have to try some of these out. Is there any in specific you would recommend from this list?

Comment: I recommend this one: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef?SRC=Home

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 2):

You could try Resharper. It's useful as it can find errors and indicate when code can be refactored.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: He is already using resharper - "...I am using resharper which is great..."